# Displays error while select radio button in selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testcase, eclipse, chrome

I'm writing testcases to select 7 radio buttons. While select the radio button it displays run time error.

I have tried with below code :

```
public void selecttemplate()
{

    List<WebElement> rdBtn = driver.findElements(By.name("Template_Type"));             
    int size=rdBtn.size();

    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        String val=rdBtn.get(i).getAttribute("value");

        if(val.equals("Documents"))
        {
            rdBtn.get(i).click();
            break;
        }
    }
    WebElement save=driver.findElement(By.name("register-button"));
    save.submit();
}
```

Below is error snap:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the html code for the respective elements on which action should be done

Comment: i have add screenshot please check

Comment: Can you please put whole error stack trace ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand from this stack trace it is issue of `Element is not clickable`.

For this exception, following problem :

> 1. Page is not loaded properly. So you need to wait for page and all component to load. Here is the code :

```
     public void selecttemplate()
     {

    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    List<WebElement> rdBtn = driver.findElements(By.name("Template_Type"));             
    int size=rdBtn.size();

    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
    String val=rdBtn.get(i).getAttribute("value");

    if(val.equals("Documents"))
    {
        // wait - recommended case 
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(rdBtn.get(i)));

       //Use Thread.sleep(); Not recommended. Use only in last working case 
       //Thread.sleep(4000);
       rdBtn.get(i).click();
        //Thread.sleep(4000);
        break;
    }
    }
    WebElement save=driver.findElement(By.name("register-button"));
    save.submit();
    }
```

---

> 2. Web Element is not on visible screen or Visible area:

- Scroll to that element and perform click operation

---

> 3. Some ajax event perform while clicking :

- Same solution as Point Num : 1

**Note : Choose your problem and perform the solution.**